# Meteor: Calling verifyEmail From React Client?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've read many SO posts about `using Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink` and `Accounts.verifyEmail`, but I haven't yet found one that seems to explain how to call them from a React client.

I have React Router set up to route clicks on the email verification link, to a React component called `ConfirmEmail`. The router captures the validation token to `props.match.params.emailValidationToken`.

The `ConfirmEmail` component looks like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

function ConfirmEmail(props) {
    const {client, match, history} = props;

    const doSetUp = useRef(true);
    const emailVerificationToken = useRef(props.match.params.emailValidationToken);

    if (doSetUp.current){
        doSetUp.current = false;
        debugger;
        Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done) {
            Accounts.verifyEmail(emailVerificationToken.current, function(error) {
                debugger;
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                    console.log(success)
                }
            })
        });
    }


    return (
        <p>Your email address has been verified.</p>
    )
}

export default ConfirmEmail;
```

I've tried it a few different ways, but I haven't yet found an approach that works.

What is the correct way to handle a click on a Meteor email validation link from a React client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't use React Hooks but I guess you will find easy to port it up to your flavor.

It all need to happen in componentDidMount(). This ensures that you avail of the token and that you only run this process once.
In the following code, `toastr` is a UI notification system for the client.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux' // if you use redux, here it is used to get the user slug from props.
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types' // not relevant
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'
import { toastr } from 'react-redux-toastr' // not relevant
import { TiWarningOutline, TiThumbsOk } from '../../components/shared/Icons/icons' // not relevant

class ConfirmEmail extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      linkExpired: false,
      logged: true // I need to know if the user is logged in before I test the token
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const { match, history, slug } = this.props
    const token = match.params.token

    // If the user is not logged in I cannot test the token against an email.
    if (!slug) {
      this.setState({ logged: false })
      return
    }

    Accounts.verifyEmail(token, err => {
      if (err && err.reason === 'Verify email link expired') {
        this.setState({ linkExpired: true })
      }
      // Inform the user what went wrong
      if (err) {
        toastr.light('Could not verify email!', `Error: ${err.reason}`, { timeOut: 2000, icon: (<TiWarningOutline style={{ fontSize: 42, color: 'red' }} />) })
      } else {
        // Confirm to user and move on to where you want to direct the user first or ask the user to close the window...or else
        toastr.light('You\'ve Successfully Confirmed Your Email Address!', { timeOut: 4000, icon: (<TiThumbsOk style={{ fontSize: 42, color: 'rgb(74, 181, 137)' }} />) })
        history.push('/feeds')
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { linkExpired, logged } = this.state
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 80 }}>
        {logged
          ? <>
            {linkExpired
              ? <p>This link has expired.</p>
              : <>
                <img src={`${IMAGE_BANK}/images/6.svg`} style={{ width: 36 }} /> // this is a spinner
                <p>Awaiting confirmation ...</p>
              </>}
          </>
          : <>
            <p style={{ maxWidth: 360, margin: '0 auto' }}>
              In order to verify your email address you need to be authenticated. Please sign in and try the verification link from your email one more time.
            </p>
            <br />
            <Link to='/signin' className='btn btn-primary'>Sign In</Link>
          </>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// this block is relevant in Redux context. Just gets the slug (or some other way to check if the user is logged in.)
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const currentUser = state.user.currentUser
  return {
    slug: currentUser?.slug
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(ConfirmEmail)

// from here, not so relevant
ConfirmEmail.propTypes = {
  params: PropTypes.object
}
```